# String between two strings that exist more than once C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, list

I have an XML file as string. 
I want to filter the value from this string that is located between two given strings (between two tags).

These two strings (tags) can occur more than once.

My string is:

```
public string text = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Userlist> <User1 userid="123" agreement="true"> <firstname>Daniel</firstname> <lastname>Brown</lastname> </User1> <User2 userid="124" agreement="false"> <firstname>Charlie</firstname> <lastname>Walsh</lastname> </User2> </Userlist>"
```

e.g. I would like to have all strings from the following string that are between `<firstname>` and `</firstname>`.

Thank`s a lot.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what is needed. Code is generally the common language that helps understand when the question itself is unclear. Please post the code you have in a [mcve] and sometimes it helps to write your question in you native language then use Google Translate to have that text translated into English to be posted here.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is?
I think everything is understandable except for grammatical errors. 
The friends who wrote the solution below have understood it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use XML library to parse xml.  Not string methods.  To get unique items you should use GroupBy and then take first item.  A Group by produces a two dimensional array List>.  GroupBy creates unique keys and then First get one item from each key.  See code below which uses xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);

            List<User> users = doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => new User
            {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("userid"),
                agreement = (Boolean)x.Attribute("agreement"),
                firstname = (string)x.Element("firstname"),
                lastname = (string)x.Element("lastname")
            }).ToList();

            List<User> distinct = users.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .ToList();

        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Boolean agreement { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Assuming I just want to filter the firstname. I always get null when I modify your code.

Comment: Are you using the same xml string posted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for repetition of words, replace characters like < / "" > by space character. So that way you end up with words separated by space. Now split the text in array and use Dictionary to count each occurrence by something like code below

```
            text = text.Replace('<', ' ');
            text = text.Replace('>', ' ');
            text = text.Replace('\"', ' ');
            text = text.Replace('?', ' ');
            text = text.Replace('=', ' ');
            text = text.Replace('/', ' ');

            var textAr = text.Split(' ');

            var textDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach(var word in textAr)
            {
               if(textDict.ContainsKey(word))
                {
                    textDict[word]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    textDict.Add(word, 1);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("string:       Repetition");
            foreach (var key in textDict.Keys)
            {

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) && textDict[key] > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(key + ":      " + textDict[key]);
                }
            }
```

Output I get is

string:       Repetition
Userlist:      2
User1:      2
userid:      2
agreement:      2
firstname:      4
lastname:      4
User2:      2

Comment: Why not split on multiple characters rather than replacing all the split characters with spaces first?  Or even split on a regex?  The two-step process is weird.

Comment: @Wyck you are right, the quality of code could be improved using your suggestion.